# How to see figures prepared in ...eps in Yap?

Tags: graphics, viewers, dvi

I have MikTeX 2.8, WinEdt 5.5 and Windows XP.

In the style article figure, presented in `title.eps` sometimes (unpredictable) after obtaining `.dvi` file cannot be seen in Yap, they are seen in pdf (via `dvi-pdf`). How to see these figures always?

Comment: Please indicate whether you cannot see a particluar eps picture from time to time or you cannot always see some pictures whereas other pictures are always visible. Also, it is always adviced to have the most recent version of software, MiKTeX 2.9 in your case.

Comment: It happens not always but from time to time. Certainly, I see these figures in .pdf

Answer (score 4):

Convert your `.dvi` output to pdf format with dvipdfmx or dvips+ps2pdf, or use pdflatex to compile your `.tex` file to get pdf output directly. Then you can preview the result with a pdf viewer.

DVI format does not support any image itself. Although MiKTeX's Yap can display eps figures in `.dvi` files, but the result often wrong, especially you transform the images.

Comment: YAP uses since miktex 2.5 for `dvi`-files with eps (and other postscript) in the background dvips + ghostscript. So the result should be as good as with dvips + ghostscript. Problems indicates normaly a faulty eps.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: Maybe my knowledge is still for MiKTeX 2.4. I've turned to TeX Live for years. Anyway, pdf format is still preferred for modern documents. And since newer MiKTeX uses dvips + gs, it won't be faster than pdf.

Answer (score 1):

Simple way to switch to pdflatex:

1. Remove `.eps` extentions from `\includegraphics` commands: type `\includegraphics {filename}` instead of `\includegraphics{filename.eps}`.
2. Convert eps graphics to pdf; in command prompt just type `epstopdf filename.eps`
3. Compile you source file with `pdflatex.exe` instead of `latex.exe`.

You see: it is easy! There is no need to cope with outdated DVI format.  To view compiled PDF file you can use [SumatraPDF](http://blog.kowalczyk.info/software/sumatrapdf/free-pdf-reader-ru.html) instead of Adobe Reader. SumatraPDF supports inverse search (just as YAP DVI viewer from MiKTeX does) so double click on text fragment in PDF viewer returns your back to appropriate place in you source file.